# Did St. Anthony of Padua write the "Be Satisfied with Me" prayer?

Tags: prayer, identify-this

There is a prayer floating around online called "Be Satisfied with Me" that starts off as follows:

> Everyone longs to give themselves completely to someone,
>   To have a deep soul relationship with another,
>   To be loved thoroughly and exclusively.
>
> But to a Christian, God says, “No, not until you are satisfied,
>   Fulfilled and content with being loved by Me alone,
>   With giving yourself totally and unreservedly to Me.
>   With having an intensely personal and unique relationship with Me alone.

The earliest version I can find online is [from 2004](https://www.christianforums.com/threads/poem-for-singles-be-satisfied-with-me.104767/) where it doesn't have an author listed. But [since at least 2007](http://lily-maiden.blogspot.com/2007/05/be-satisfied-with-me.html), it has been attributed to [St. Anthony of Padua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_of_Padua) (and on many more sites since like [here](http://yunho1108.blogspot.com/2010/09/be-satisfied-in-me.html), [here](http://thepracticingcatholic.com/2015/06/13/be-satisfied-with-me/), [here](http://gnm.org/prayers/be-satisfied-with-me/), and [here](https://ednarabago.wordpress.com/resources/be-satisfied-with-me/)).

I'm a bit suspicious of St. Anthony's authorship for a number of reasons given that it mostly seems to be floating around on blogs, and I find it odd for 13th Century monk to be writing a prayer about finding a spouse (and at a time when arranged marriages were more common).

Is there any reason to believe that St. Anthony of Padua actually wrote this?